# How to filter my combined column? (ng-grid)

Tags: angularjs, filtering, ng-grid

I have an ng-grid which one of his column is a combined column:

```
angular.forEach($scope.opportunitiesData,function(row){
            row.getABDisplayName = function(){
                return this.a + ' - ' + this.b;
            };

        });



$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'loadGridItems',
            headerRowHeight: 0,
            multiSelect: false,
            showFilter: false,
            columnDefs: [{field:'getABDisplayName()',displayName:"Tasks"},

                         ...],
            enableSorting: true,
            filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
        };
```

my problem is that the filter doesn't work on that field.
I tried to change it, and break down the combined field to 2 fields and the filter works...
not sure what is the difference, as both fields are strings.

Comment: Usually it's a better option to have a function/service for building the data you can pass it (the data) directly to setPagingData(myBuildData,page,pageSize);

Comment: the data is fetched by a factory service...but i don't see how it is related.

Comment: tomerz - check out my answer below and let me know if this helps you.  If so, plz vote as answer.  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I have been watching this as I had the same problem (only with three concatenated field for the column to filter on).  Eventually I came up with the following:

You'll need to create your own filter, and bypass the ng-grid's built-in filterOptions altogether.

Something along the lines of:

```
// pass in your original dataset to filter, and filter text
app.filter('opportunitiesFilter',function(){
    return function(array, input){

    var match = [];                // will hold your newly filtered data
    if (input = '') return array;  // return orig data if nothing entered

    // use foreach to loop through your original array  
    angular.forEach(array, function(item){

        // your filter logic goes here - might be the following:
        if (item.indexOf(input) >= 0) match.push(item);
      });
    return match;
});
```

And down in your controller code, add a watch to your search text field and call the filter when it changes.  You'll pass in your original data array and search field text to the filter, and bind the resulting filtered array to your ng-grid data param.  Be sure to include the $filter call in your controller signature.  ie. function($scope, $http, $filter, ...){ }

```
// watch your input field for changes to filter on, call custom filter, and bind to grid
$scope.watch('searchText'), function(){
    $scope.'loadGridItems' = $filter('opportunitiesFilter')($scope.opportunitiesData, $scope.searchText);
}
```

This worked for me, although you may need to tweak your filter as needed - like using .toLowerCase() etc to do case-insensitive matching and the like.

Hope this helps you out - it took me awhile but now I'm good to go.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, but you do not think this is the answer?  If you have better solution please let me know, or please mark this as answer.